# Error on Redmine "plugin redmine_git_hosting" : undefined symbol: libssh2_session_init_ex

Tags: plugins, redmine

I get an error when installing the plugin "redmine_git_hosting":

```
/opt/bitnami/ruby/bin/.ruby.bin: symbol lookup error: /opt/bitnami/apps/redmine/htdocs/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rugged-0.21.4/lib/rugged/rugged.so: undefined symbol: libssh2_session_init_ex
```

Redmine 3.0.0.stable

```
Environment:
  Redmine version                3.0.0.stable
  Ruby version                   2.0.0-p598 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux]
  Rails version                  4.2.0
  Environment                    production
  Database adapter               Mysql2
SCM:
  Subversion                     1.8.10
  Cvs                            1.12.13
  Git                            1.9.5
  Filesystem                     
Redmine plugins:
  redmine_bootstrap_kit          0.2.1
  redmine_git_hosting            1.0.2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Bitnami installation

> As Bitnami override some internal paths needed to build native Ruby
>   extension you must compile libgit2 yourself before installing Redmine
>   Git Hosting.

http://jbox-web.github.io/redmine_git_hosting/guide/bitnami-installation/